# Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C^1$ in its domain, suppose $f'(x)$ is a non-decreasing function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C^1$ in its domain, suppose $f'(x)$ is a non-decreasing function.

Using the monotonicity of $f'$, prove that the function $g(x)= f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)$ is nondecreasing on $[c,\infty)$  where $c> 0$.

Comment: Keyword: **convexity**.

Comment: Clearly $g'(x) = f'(x) -f'(c) \geq 0$ if $x \in [c, \infty)$ because of the monotonicity of $f'(x)$ and hence $g(x)$ itself is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* If $c \leqslant y < x$, then for some $d \in (y, x)$
$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(d) \geqslant f'(c).$$

Comment: thank you very much @njguliyev

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $ c  \leq y<x $, I want to show that $ g (x)-g (y) \geq 0$

to that used to

$$f(x)=f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)+ r_y(x)$$

As $r_y(x)\geq0$  and $f'(0)\leq f'(y)$, I got that replacing $ g (x)-g (y) \geq 0$